# Why calculate the residual covariances between variables with the same residuals in structural equation models?

Tags: covariance, residuals, structural-equation-modeling

I'm currently reading the book, "Latent Variable Models".

Today, I've encountered the following.

[image]

[image]

The pictures are the structural equation model and its solution.

$A_1$ represents the affection measured in time 1, $A_2$ is the affection in time 2.

Similarly, $T_1$, $L_1$, $C_1$, and $D_1$ respectively mean thought, love, confirmation, and dating measured in time 1.

As you can see, the path coefficients connecting the measured variables with latent variables (from $A_x$ to $T_x$, $L_x$, $C_x$, $D_x$) are identical in both times.

But what I don't understand is the residual covariances denoted by $i$, $j$, $k$, and $l$.

For instance, $i$ here, if I understood correctly, means the residual covariance between $T_1$ and $T_2$, both of which have the identical residual, $e$.

It feels like that because the residuals of $T_1$ and $T_2$ are identical regardless whether on which time it was measured ($e=e$) it's meaningless to calculate them.

Why is it necessary to calculate the residual covariances between variables with an identical residual?

What's the benefit from doing so?

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: The individual residuals aren't identical.  Rather, the residual for person p, measure m, is always drawn from the same population distribution.  The 2 residuals at time 1 & time 2 are likely to be more similar to each other when coming from the same person, than when coming from different people.

Comment: Then why they are not denoted by different subscripts or different alphabets? For instance e1 and e2?

Comment: Some books parameterize the residual variances as fixed at 1, with manifest variables freely "loading" on their residuals.  The residual variances (e-squared, f-squared, etc. in the table you posted) are the square of their loading.  Most books I have read equivalently parameterize the residuals' loading matrix as identity (or actually they drop it altogether) and freely estimate the diagonal of the residual covariance matrix (often Theta, sometimes Psi).  A benefit of this book's parameterization is residual covariances are correlation.  But it doesn't match SEM software implementations.